# closing jquery dialog from an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have created a jquery dialog with an Iframe in it that's a form and I would like the dialog to close when the user hits cancel's or submits the form in the dialog...

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "option", "title",["Create"] );
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
$("#dialog-content").html("<iframe id='iframe_manage' width='825px' height='800px' class='popup_iframe' src='manage.php?PME_sys_operation=Add&pv=popup'></iframe>");
```

thoughts?

i tried something like this..

```
$("#iframe_manage").load(function () {
    $('input[name=PME_sys_canceladd]').click(function() {
        alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
        //$('input[name=PME_sys_canceladd]').submit();
    });
});
```

but doesn't seem to pick up the click event on the button..

Comment: Try this: `this.contentWindow.$("input...` inside the load handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be doing this

```
$("iframe").contents().find()
```

instead of just using $().

So maybe this would work:

```
$("#iframe_manage").load(function () {
    $("#iframe_manage").contents().find('input[name=PME_sys_canceladd]').click(function() {
        alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
        //$('input[name=PME_sys_canceladd]').submit();
    });
});
```